# Создание файла с именем переменной

Tags: pascal

Как создать с помощью Pascal, файл с расширением php, в определённом каталоге и с именем переменной?

В папке 3, должен создаваться файл X.php. Так вот не могу понять, как связать файловую переменную со строчной. Если в Assign добавляю X, то файл создаётся в рабочем каталоге паскаля, а когда прописываю путь '`C:\папка1\папка2\папка3`', то становится мне непонятным как и куда втулить X.

```
var X : string;
    f : text;

begin
   Writeln('название файла');
   Readln(X);
   Assign(f, 'C:\папка1\папка2\папка3');
   ReWrite(f)
end.
```

Comment: Без обид, но про конкатенацию твой же вопрос [тут][1] я помечаю вопрос как "Работа за автора" т.к. из своего первого вопроса Не был вынесен ответ и думать Вы отказываетесь сами.


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/85018/

Comment: Да уж, так сказать не зделал выводы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Assign(f, 'C:\папка1\папка2\папка3\'+X+'.php');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Assign(f, 'C:\папка1\папка2\папка3\'+X);
```

ЗЫ Почитайте про [конкатенацию строк](http://www.vzmakh.ru/info/pascal/modules/page6.html).